# What kind of creature is yoda?

Tags: star-wars

I've always wondered why there was only one creature like yoda in the star wars movies. Was he really one of a kind or does he appear in other media?

I'm trying to determine if there are enough of his kind to divulge a race.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [the wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda%27s_species):

> For reasons unknown, George Lucas maintains a strict policy of keeping the history, name, origin, and whereabouts of this species unknown.
>
> When asked what species Yoda is, Lucas has only joked, "He's a frog."

There was another of Yoda's species on the Jedi Council during the events of *The Phantom Menace*. Her name was [Yaddle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yaddle).

Comment: Yaddle is a female, I updated. Otherwise a correct answer.